# He had taken 5 fewer apples

Tags: word-usage

> - Please wait 5 more minutes.*

Could I use *fewer* instead of *more*?

> He had taken 5 fewer apples.

Comment: @smock Please be careful when suggesting edits to not change the text that is being asked about. Grammatical errors in that text should be addressed by answers, not by editing.

Comment: @sinbadsuuny You can take more care when posting the question.  Always use a spellchecker. Note the spelling of "minutes" is not correct. A spellchecker would have corrected this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as *fewer* is the opposite of *more*.

You should note the difference between *fewer* and *less*.

You usually use *less* with uncountable nouns and *fewer* with plural nouns.

E.g.

> He took fewer apples.
>
> He took less apple sauce.

However, *more* is used with both countable and uncountable nouns:

> He took more apples.
>
> He took more apple sauce.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is yes, you can use "fewer" in the same way as "more". You'll often, sometimes incorrectly, hear "less" used instead of "fewer". I wouldn't get too hung-up on that difference since most native English speakers (at least in America) don't bother with using it correctly anyway.

On a separate note, you should use the simple or perfect past tense of "take" in your sample sentence. "He *has* taken five fewer apples", He *had* taken five fewer apples", or "He *took* five fewer apples" could all be correct based on context.

Comment: It is debatable whether 'less' is 'incorrect' for countable items. The Cambridge Guide to English Usage describes the choice "between the more formal fewer and the more spontaneous less" as a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

For count nouns, you should use fewer

> He has fewer apples

For (singular) mass nouns, you should use less

> He has less water

As [this site](https://www.dictionary.com/e/fewer-vs-less/) suggests,

> *If you can count it, go for fewer. If you can’t, opt for less.*

Note that *more* applies to both situations